# Groovy closure not work with static final field from super class

Tags: groovy, static, closures, final

```
class Parent {
    final static String newLine = "*"
}
class Child extends Parent{
    List body = [3, 4, 5]
    String toString() {
        def str = new StringBuilder()
        body.each { str.append(it + newLine) }
        str
    }
}

def c = new Child()
println c
```

The above is one trivial sample to illustrate the problem. It couldn't be compiled using `Groovy plugin` on `Eclipse`. Remove either `final` or `static` in the field of super class solves the problem. However, I have no idea why it's the case.

http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+Beans
In this link it mentions the rules for property and fields used in Groovy. I suppose the one applied should be the last one, i.e. meta class. Unfortunately, I still couldn't understand the behavior.

The behavior is reproduced consistently in all versions of Groovy. Maybe someone could report one bug to Groovy team. I have never done this before. It would be more efficient if someone experienced could do that.

Comment: Yeah, using str.append(it + super.newLine) works too..as does making the field public. In groovyConsole the error is: "BUG! exception in phase 'class generation' in source unit 'ConsoleScript2' Trying to access private constant field [Parent#newLine] from inner class" which is a hint that the problem is that groovy is making that field private by default for some reason. I'm not sure why though.

Comment: Groovy is make fields private by default, but generate getters and setters as well. "super.newLine" is not direct access. Instead, it's using getter implicitly. However, why Groovy couldn't do the this when final and static is added?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most probably https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-5776 which is more difficult to fix than it looks like

Comment: @blackdragb It seems one very old [bug](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-5259), which is claimed fixed, but apparently not. [5776](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-5776) doesn't seem to describe this problem properly, for removing either static or final will make the compiler happy. Thank you for pointing out the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

As blackdrag already pointed out: it's a bug.
But another workaround is to add the `protected` keyword:

```
protected final static String newLine = "*"
```