# Private static field not accessible from a nested closure

Tags: grails, groovy, slf4j

Say I have the following classes:

```
@Slf4j
class MySuperclass {

    public void testMethod() {
        def test = [1, 2, 3]
        test.each {it ->
            log.info("gab" + it)
            def test2 = [4,5,6]
            test2.each {
                log.info("" + it)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then:

```
class MySubclass extends MySuperclass {

    public void process() {
        testMethod()
    }
}
```

When I call `mySubclass.process()`, I get an error:

```
No such property log for class: com.ingenuity.app.kang.batch.MySubclass
```

The error is thrown only for the line inside the test2 closure. If I declare a public log field, it works fine. It also works fine if I add a `@Slf4j` annotation in the subclass.

I don't understand what happens here. Is this a groovy bug? 
I found this issue which might be related, but it is not the same behaviour:
[Groovy closure not work with static final field from super class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14552964/groovy-closure-not-work-with-static-final-field-from-super-class)

Comment: I guess this link https://projectlombok.org/features/log might give you some ideas of resolving your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to deal with it is to reference the log property as a static member on the class.  The project at https://github.com/jeffbrown/logissue demonstrates that.

https://github.com/jeffbrown/logissue/blob/d089c296c102980855a88061275e52485965e4ab/src/main/groovy/logdemo/MySuperclass.groovy

```
package logdemo

import groovy.util.logging.Slf4j

@Slf4j
class MySuperclass {

    void testMethod() {
        def test = [1, 2, 3]
        test.each {it ->
            log.info("gab" + it)
            def test2 = [4,5,6]
            test2.each {
                MySuperclass.log.info("" + it)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That works.

```
~ $ git clone git@github.com:jeffbrown/logissue.git
Cloning into 'logissue'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 22, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (22/22), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (15/15), done.
remote: Total 22 (delta 0), reused 22 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (22/22), 53.62 KiB | 1.28 MiB/s, done.
~ $ cd logissue/
  $ ./gradlew run

> Task :run
16:41:19.022 [main] INFO  logdemo.MySuperclass - gab1
16:41:19.027 [main] INFO  logdemo.MySuperclass - 4
16:41:19.027 [main] INFO  logdemo.MySuperclass - 5
16:41:19.027 [main] INFO  logdemo.MySuperclass - 6
16:41:19.027 [main] INFO  logdemo.MySuperclass - gab2
16:41:19.027 [main] INFO  logdemo.MySuperclass - 4
16:41:19.027 [main] INFO  logdemo.MySuperclass - 5
16:41:19.027 [main] INFO  logdemo.MySuperclass - 6
16:41:19.027 [main] INFO  logdemo.MySuperclass - gab3
16:41:19.027 [main] INFO  logdemo.MySuperclass - 4
16:41:19.027 [main] INFO  logdemo.MySuperclass - 5
16:41:19.027 [main] INFO  logdemo.MySuperclass - 6

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 2s
2 actionable tasks: 2 executed
```

Comment: Thanks Jeff. Yeah, as stated in the question, I found a workaround for it. I was just wondering if this is a bug or I am just doing something wrong.

Comment: I think it is.  The behavior you are describing is related to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-5776 (maybe not exactly the same).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see that one. I'll accept the answer.

Answer (score -1):

You need add log dependencies in MySuperClass, like:

```
import groovy.util.logging.Slf4j

@Grapes([
    @Grab(group='ch.qos.logback', module='logback-classic', version='1.0.13') 
])

@Slf4j
class MySuperclass {
...
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is the issue.

Comment: It is like in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577596/how-can-i-use-log-inside-a-src-groovy-class/5912841

Comment: The `logback` dependency will be needed to make the logging work, but has nothing to do with the not being able to access a private static member from the nested closure.